# Vanishing geometry in BLender 4.0 when approaching in 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view

Since I first installed Blender 4.0 I constantly have issues with vanishing geometry.
If the distance to the objects is great, everything is visible. When I approach some of the objects vanish depending on the viewing angle.
I checked and modified the clip start and end settings in the view panel.
No change.

When I open the exact same file in Blender 3.6 everything is fine.
All addons are the same in both versions.

And it's not limited to one particular file. I have this issue with every file so far.
Even when I start from scratch.

[image]

Any hints what causes this problem or even how to setup and clean my system to get rid of all blender settings to start with a clean installation?
I'd like to switch my working base to Blender 4.0 because of the improvement in lighting, geometry nodes and other things. But since they change the BSDF and several other settings you can indeeed open a Blender 4.0 file with 3.6 but in almost all cases you have to check and change shadings and other stuff to work again.
[image: Good]
[image: Bad]

Comment: I downloaded your file, and didn't find any issue. Could you upload a screenshot showing the problem?

Comment: I've the issue too with this file. when zooming to the center of the scene, objects around disappear and should not.

Answer (score 1):

Your Viewport's Clipping range is insanely huge for no reason:

[image]

> A large clipping range will allow you to see both near and far objects, but reduces the depth precision resulting in artifacts.
>
> In some cases, a very large range may cause operations that depend on
> the depth buffer to become unreliable, although this depends on the
> graphics card and drivers.
>
> **Source: [Editors > 3D Viewport > Sidebar — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/sidebar.html#view-panel)**

When you drastically change the clipping range, you should try to keep it reasonably as small as possible.

Your scene here is 200m long. But your viewport is set to render anything from 1cm up to 1 000 000m away. That's a 1:100 000 000 ratio. The default values are 0.01 m up to 1000m and are completely fine with your scene.

You can revert those values to their default state by hovering them with your mouse and pressing <kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
This works much better. But I didn't think about this point as it worked fine in 3.6
And the huge values of theclipping end resume of some cloud fields I inserted which are way bigger than 200 meters.

O.k 4.0 - I',m coming!